# How to add custom button to datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have datatable that should have 'Add' button. Here is example of the table:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tbl-level').DataTable({
    order: [
      [0, "asc"]
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 2,
      searchable: true,
      orderable: false,
      visible: true
    }],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      text: '<span class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add',
      attr: {
        id: 'btn-add-review'
      },
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
        alert('Button activated');
      },
      initComplete: function() {
        console.log('Test');
        var btns = $('#btn-add-review');
        btns.addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm');
        btns.removeClass('dt-button');
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.bootstrap4.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tbl-level">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-custom">
      <th class="text-center">Level</th>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Level 1</button></td>
      <td>4 Year Period</td>
      <td>This is a test for level 1.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Level 2</button></td>
      <td>3 Year Period</td>
      <td>This is a test for level 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Level 3</button></td>
      <td>2 Year Period</td>
      <td>This is a test for level 3.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Level 4</button></td>
      <td>1 Year Period</td>
      <td>This is a test for level 4.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

If you runt he snippet above you will see 'Add' button but there is no Select menu for entries. Second problem is that button is not on the same line as 'Search' field. I would like to have this layout:

```
Show 10 entries       Add Button             Search
```

I still didn't find the way to get this layout, and `initComplete` was never triggered. If you know solution for this issue please let me know.

Comment: Your `initComplete` is not firing because it's embedded in the `buttons` section of your table definition. You need to move it to after the `buttons` section - then it will fire.

Comment: I didn't understand the comment "_there is no Select menu for entries_" - can you clarify?

Comment: @andrewjames If you remove button code from datatable you will see drop down menu with option of how many records user can see per page. That drop down is not visible since I added button.

Comment: Understood now - thank you.  I think there are too many differences between my set-up and yours - I cannot recreate that specific problem.